# Убрать лишние пробелы и табы в std::string строке

Tags: c++, строки

Допустим есть строка с именем процессора, которую возвращает функция `GetProcessorName()`:

```
// "Intel<R> Core<TM>2 Duo  CPU    P8400  @ 2.26GHz"
std::string some_string = GetProcessorName();
```

Необходимо убрать лишние пробелы. То есть, отформатировать строку так, чтобы между словами не было лишних пробелов или знаков табуляции. Вот так:

```
// "Intel<R> Core<TM>2 Duo CPU P8400 @ 2.26GHz";
```

Пробовал `replace` & `replace_if`, в конце-концов понял, что эти и подобные им алгоритмы предназначены исключительно для контейнеров. Возможно лямбды помогут. Что посоветуете делать с `std::string`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

вообще то `std::string` - это обычный контейнер. такой же, как обычный `std::vector`.

Если не хочется `remove`/`remove_if` и душа требует лямбд, можно так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    std::string some_string = "Intel<R> Core<TM>2 Duo  CPU    P8400  @ 2.26GHz";
    auto end = std::unique(some_string.begin(), some_string.end(), [](char l, char r){
        return std::isspace(l) && std::isspace(r) && l == r;
    });

    std::cout << std::string(some_string.begin(), end) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

**UPD**

Некоторые предлагают переписать условие

```
std::isspace(l) && std::isspace(r) && l == r
```

как

```
std::isspace(l) && l == r
```

я бы его все таки переписал как

```
std::isspace(l) && std::isspace(r)
```

Почему? В вопросе звучит "удалить лишние пробелы и табы". А если строка такая (символ подчеркивания - это пробел, а `\t` - табуляция)

```
a\t\t__\t_\tb
```

то ее наверно правильно было бы сократить до `a_b`, а не `a\t_\t_\tb`.

Но если посмотреть, что именно проверяет [`std::isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace), то узнаете, что перевод строки (`\n`) также считается. Поэтому, если строка будет многострочной вида `abc_\n_def`, то она будет сокращена до `abc_def`, что может быть не совсем то, что хочется. Кстати, это вариант ближе к варианту с регуляркой в ответе @GreenDragon, так как `\s` работает как [`isspace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/).

Comment: Лямбда у меня вызывает: error C2780: 'bool std::isspace(_Elem,const std::locale &)': expects 2 arguments - 1 provided. Описание в редакторе: no instance of function template "str::isspace" matches the argument list. Argument type are: (char)

Comment: `<cctype>` подключали?

Comment: возможно, древний компилятор http://ideone.com/sJXjDI

Comment: Убрал `std::isspace( l )`  & `std::isspace( r )` - всё заработало.

Comment: Один `std::isspace` можно убрать.

Comment: @VBS - оно теперь будет любые дубликаты удалять:)

Comment: @VBS без `std::isspace` вообще у Вас `8400` превратится в `840`, например.

Comment: @VBS: "Убрал ... всё заработало." Что значит "заработало"? Скомпилировалось? Это у нас теперь назвается "заработало"? :)

Comment: @KoVadim: Ну, скажем так, `std::string` - отнюдь не обычный `std::vector`. Уже наличие нулевого терминатора, доступного через оператор `[]` с нелегальным для `std::vector` индексом `size()` делает его далеко не таким обычным.

Comment: Как сказал Майерс, std::string может быть реализован по разному, более того, там есть много вариантов реализации. И никто не мешает реализовать на std::vector, как наиболее близкому.

Comment: @KoVadim: "Реализовать `std::string` на `std::vector`" и "`std::string`- это обычный `std::vector`" - эти утверждения даже отдаленно не имеют ничего общего. Особенно в контексте данного вопроса, где стандартные контейнеры выступают на уровне своей интерфейсной спецификации.

Answer (score 3):

Ну а чем `string` не контейнер? :)
Сами убедитесь:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string s = "Intel<R>               Core<TM>2 Duo  CPU    P8400  @ 2.26GHz";
    s = s.substr(0,distance(s.begin(),remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(),
                 [](const char& a) { return (a == ' ') && (*(&a+1) == ' '); })));

    cout << "[" << s << "]\n";

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Для работы с текстом можно использовать регулярные выражения.
Начиная с C++11 в стандартной библиотеке [появилась](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/) их поддержка, поэтому вашу задачу также можно решить следующим способом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
  std::string str= "Intel<R> Core<TM>2 Duo  CPU    P8400  @ 2.26GHz";
  std::regex e("(\\s)+");
  std::cout << std::regex_replace (str,e,"$1")<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Исходник релиза увеличился с 34 до 70 KB. Не самый лучший вариант в данном случае. Но за необычный, да ещё и исключительно короткий пример решения моей задачи - спасибо. О их присутствии в C++11 я даже не знал. Ради читабельности изучу эти замечательные выражения.

Comment: @VBS если ответ Вам нравится, голосуйте (стрелки слева).

Answer (score 1):

Немного упрощенный вариант кода @KoVadim [под c++03](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mh1ZB2dTp5cuKVh9):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

bool space2(char l, char r) {
    return l == r && std::isspace(l);
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "Intel<R> Core<TM>2 Duo  CPU    P8400  @ 2.26GHz";
    std::cout << std::string(s.begin(), std::unique(s.begin(), s.end(), space2)) << '\n';
}
```